# how to can have both RTL and LTR theme?

Tags: css, margin, right-to-left

i have script with LTR css and i want this in RTL
that site have both RTL and LTR
this is LTR code:

```
.search-form input.span6
{
float:left;
margin-left: 0px;
}
```

and i have to have above code for RTL

```
.search-form input.span6
{
    float:right;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

how can have margin-left without value?

Comment: Do you mean you want to override the existing value for `margin-left` with the default value? In that case, I have bad news; the default (initial) value is already 0.

Comment: see, default code in ltr have `margin-left: 0px;` i want change and overwrite this with `margin-right: 0px;` . do you understand? if i just write `margin-right:initial` in this case load `margin-left: 0px;` again. i want dont load this

Comment: I wish your question made sense, I really do.

Comment: thanks,but it dosent work!!!